# Equivalent of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm building a Qt project with CMake and on the command line I have to give `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path-to-qt>` for CMake to be able to find Qt.

Now I opened this project in CLion and as expected it didn't find Qt. What is the CLion equivalent of `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...` on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open the CMake panel (press the CMake button on the toolbar at the bottom of the main window). The goto CMake settings like shown below:

[image: cmake panel]

In the settings dialog you can now configure CMake as required and also set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` option:

[image: cmake settings]

Comment: Do I need to put `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` or is it _still_ implicit, even when I add my own options?

Comment: @AndreKR It depends on the Build type setting the the field above the red highlighted one.