# Can't compile c++ program with OpenCV. OpenCVConfig.cmake file missing

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake

Tried to run my simple cpp program from CLion and also from terminal, but everywhere have the same problem:

```
By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

---

Tried some solutions, but nothing helped. OpenCV is installed into user directory on macOS. Could someone help me?

Comment: How did you install **OpenCV** exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell via terminal... using homebrew, python3 and installing virtual environment and cmake

Comment: What is your cmake command? The error message is telling you that you'll need to add OpenCV's installation prefix to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. This means your cmake command should contain `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path to opencv>`.

Comment: You can find the file @Richard is referring to like this `find /usr /Users -iname "OpenCVConfig.cmake" 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with CLion in Windows when I tried to run a program I wrote on a different system. To fix the problem I had to "Import Project from Sources" so that CLion would generate all the necessary files for Make.

I imported the existing program through the dialog box that popped up after I Imported.

[image: CLion Start-up Window]

This was my simple GCD c++ terminal program before I imported the repo the way CLion required me to:

[image: GCD Project Files]

After I chose import CLion generated all the files necessary to compile locally:

[image: My new project file architecture]

I hope this helps, once I got my program imported CLion did everything else. I modified my CMakeList.txt file for c++11 because I need to know my programs compile as expected on 11. CLion defaulted to c++14 for my.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states, what to do to resolve it: First, find where one of the mentioned files (`OpenCVConfig.cmake` or `opencv-config.cmake`) is located on your system. This path will be `/path/to/configfile`. Then set the `OpenCV_DIR` variable accordingly.

Setting the variable can be done in two ways:

- command line: `cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=</path/to/configfile> <any additional arguments>`
- CLion settings: See images below (taken from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456060/579698)). But instead of `-DENABLE_TESTS=ON` add `-DOpenCV_DIR=</path/to/configfile>` to CMake options:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
```

So look for the file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` and in your `CMakeLists.txt` file set the variable `OpenCV_DIR` to the directory containing the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file.

In my case I had installed opencv from the source. The directory where I had installed opencv had the following structure

```
opencv-installation-directory/
  - bin/
  - include/
  - lib/
  - share/
    - OpenCV/
      - OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

So I added the following line to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR opencv-installation-directory/share/OpenCV)
```